# What is the error in the xml file that that says Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I started to learn android studio. I am getting an xml file error with relative layout please have a look moreover i have some missing/deleted xml content that is causing error.Please have a look and help me.
The current activity_main.xml code is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  
tools:context="com.mindbuzz.big.calculator.MainActivity">  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">  
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
android:id="@+id/toolbar"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"  
android:background="#ed0d0d"  
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />  
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>  
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton  
android:id="@+id/fab"  
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"`enter code here`  
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin  "
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
android:layout_height="match_parent" />  
<include layout="@layout/content_main"  
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"  
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/appBarLayout"  
android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout" />  
</ android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content">  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hers's the error for rendering in preview :
Rendering Problems

NOTE:

```
This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.
```

NOTE:

```
One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.<br /
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout> does not set the required layout_width attribute: Set to wrap_content, Set to match_parent<br />
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout> does not set the required layout_height attribute:     Set to wrap_content, Set to match_parent<br />
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> does not set the required layout_width attribute: Set to wrap_content, Set to match_parent<br /
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> does not set the required layout_height attribute: Set to wrap_content, Set to match_parent<br /
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton> does not set the required layout_width attribute: Set to wrap_content, Set to match_parent <br />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton> does not set the required layout_height attribute: Set to wrap_content, Set to match_parent <br />
Or: Automatically add all missing attributes
```

Gradle build shows following errors :

```
Error:(3) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
Error:(3) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have this `</ android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">`?

Comment: @codeMagic The tut i was referring used it with describing it to enclose all the content in the current layout.

Comment: @BHASKAR, sorry, but that comment is not grammatical or understandable English.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually see very clearly in your posted code where the errors are by noting where the syntax highlighter can't make sense of it. There's nonsense at the beginning (`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`), and more nonsense further down (`</ android:layout_width="wrap_content"`), both indicated by StackOverflow helpfully showing the text in grey rather than coloured.